# How to solve azure keyvault secrets (Unauthorized) AKV10032: Invalid issuer. error in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure, pycharm

I am using the [azure-keyvault-secrets](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/tree/master/sdk/keyvault/azure-keyvault-secrets) package to manage my resources secrets in Python 3.8, developping in [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/).

But when I am running the following:

```
import os
from azure.keyvault.secrets import SecretClient
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential

VAULT_URL = os.environ["VAULT_URL"]

credential = DefaultAzureCredential()
client = SecretClient(
    vault_url=VAULT_URL,
    credential=credential
)
client.set_secret('my-secret-name', 'my-secret-value')
```

I get the following error:

```
HttpResponseError: azure keyvault secrets (Unauthorized) AKV10032: Invalid issuer. error
```

I have set the environment variables correct, according to the [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/azure/key-vault/secrets/quick-create-python). I also restarted the runtime environment in PyCharm multiple times.

What to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I also faced the same issue. Following solution worked for me:

1. Login into Azure portal and check how many subscriptions you have. Check under which subscription/ Resource Group the Key Vault is under.
2. Login into Azure CLI and execute the following command:

```
az account list --output table
```

3. Make the subscription which has the KeyVault as the default one:

```
az account set --subscription "subscription name"
```

4. Re execute the code :

```
import os
from azure.keyvault.secrets import SecretClient
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential

VAULT_URL = os.environ["VAULT_URL"]

credential = DefaultAzureCredential()
client = SecretClient(
    vault_url=VAULT_URL,
    credential=credential
)
client.set_secret('my-secret-name', 'my-secret-value')
```

It should work.

Comment: I use the azure CLI command "azure login" in the anaconda prompt window, then launch pycharm from that same prompt window.  I noticed that I can use the "az account set..." command AFTER launching pycharm and the code in pycharm notices the change.