# Azure CLI login with Pycharm

Tags: azure, pycharm, azure-keyvault

I have an active anaconda environment and sign in to azure with

```
az login
```

then I run the code in Pycharm (I set the python interpreter to the environment) but the access to the keyvault raises an exception

```
credentials = DefaultAzureCredential()
secret_client = SecretClient(vault_url, credentials)

secret = secret_client.get_secret("my-secret")
>>> azure.core.exceptions.HttpResponseError: (Unauthorized) AKV10032: Invalid issuer. Expected one of https://sts.windows
```

The authentication works if I start the script from command line- so I think this is somehow related to Pycharm. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62971796/how-to-solve-azure-keyvault-secrets-unauthorized-akv10032-invalid-issuer-err  Does this help?

Comment: Yes, this is related to Pycharm that could not access your login status. You can use ClientSecretCredential to access your key vault as a workaround.

Comment: Great, do you know the reason why Pycharm can not access the login status? Does the ClientSecretCredential cause any issue in an azure function or during the pipeline testing/deployment?

Comment: As I found out one has to provide 'tenant_id', 'client_id', and 'client_secret' when using ClientSecretCredential. This seems not to be a valid solution when I think in terms of security.