# Azure Function + Rider Credential issue resulting in "Message: AKV10032" error

Tags: python, azure, rider

I am trying to debug and work with an Azure function in Rider - this error only occurs when I run it locally, deploying the function to Azure works correctly.

When I run the this block of code

```
default_credentials = DefaultAzureCredential()
    keyvault = SecretClient(
        vault_url=azure_shared.key_vault,
        credential=default_credentials
    )

    api_key = keyvault.get_secret("apikey").value
```

I get the following error:

```
ClientAuthenticationError: (Unauthorized) AKV10032: Invalid issuer. Expected one of https://sts.windows.net/xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-4a5f0358090a/, https://sts.windows.net/xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-5f571e91255a/, https://sts
.windows.net/xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-dee5fc7331f4/, found https://sts.windows.net/xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-579c58293b4b/.
```

I only have one subscription.
`AZ ACCOUNT SHOW` confirms the account I am logged in as is the one ending in **90a**, so an expected account.

However, if I run `AZ LOGIN` and login with my *work* account, the tenantId is the **b4b** one.

Why the heck is Rider / Azure Functions using a different credential that I have provided?  Is it stored somewhere locally?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you [JamesTran-MSFT | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/users/jamestran-msft/) and [User Madhanlal - Stack Overflow Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11049287/madhanlal). Posting your suggestions as answer to help other community members.

You can try below way to resolve  `AKV10032: Invalid issuer. Expected one of https://sts.windows.net/...` error:

**This error could be cross-tenant issue;**
If you set the sub as default just before, it should work:

```
az account set --subscription {SubID}
az keyvault secret list --vault-name myVault
```

**Re-execuate the code**:

```
default_credentials = DefaultAzureCredential()
keyvault = SecretClient(
vault_url=azure_shared.key_vault,
credential=default_credentials
)
api_key = keyvault.get_secret("apikey").value
```

References: [Unable to retrieve password from keyvault - ERROR: AKV10032: Invalid issuer - Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/714417/unable-to-retrieve-password-from-keyvault-error-ak.html) and [How to solve azure keyvault secrets (Unauthorized) AKV10032: Invalid issuer. error in Python - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62971796/how-to-solve-azure-keyvault-secrets-unauthorized-akv10032-invalid-issuer-err/67673042#67673042)

Comment: This does not resolve the issue.  The subscription is linked up correctly, and I can query the Key Vaults with az, however, running the application with func start, tries to query the key vault with the wrong credential.

Comment: You can refer to similar issues: https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/7607, https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/11871